# Reference Request for Ordinary Differential Equation problem book

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I am looking for a good problem book in Ordinary Differential Equations at Graduate's level.
Can someone suggest me the book for problem practice.
To be precise our study revolves around the analysis of solutions of ordinary differential equations.
Its not just about finding the general solution of an ordinary differential equation.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[George Simmons: Differential Equations with Applications and Historical Notes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1498702597)

There are many good problems in this book..

For study of solution try [Birkhoff and Rota: Ordinary Differential Equations](https://www.amazon.ca/Ordinary-Differential-Equations-Garrett-Birkhoff/dp/0471860034?tag=duckduckgo-ffnt-20)